# Sending emails to multiple recipients using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook, mapi

My vbscript sends email to automatically to a recipient, but does anyone know how to add more than one recipient to it?

```
...
Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail
MyTime = Now

ToAddress = "email@address.com"
MessageSubject = "It works!."
MessageBody = "Good job on that script." 
MessageAttachment = some attachment
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & vbCrLf & MyTime
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
newMail.Send
```

This is what I have right now. And it works fine. But, I'd like to have more than one recipients. Thanks in advance.

```
newMail.CC = "person1@domain1.org;person2@domain2.org;person3@domain3.org"
```

This above line worked!

And it works the same way with .BCC, in case anyone wants to not to display the contacts' list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `MailItem.Recipients.Add` for each recipient or set the `To`/`CC`/`BCC` properties to a `";"` separated list of addresses.